# Google Place API's type filter

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

So, I'm sending a request asking for establishments places as follow:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=&radius=40&type=establishment&language=pt_BR&key=

But unfortunately i'm getting places of type route, locality and political as well.

Comment: I need to fetch only establishments from this endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting mix types is because the type/s "establishment" is already deprecated. It is no longer supported in the type filter of a place search, or in the types property when adding a place. You can read about this in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table2).

Comment: Thanks. But what should i use then? Put all the types in the parameter?

Comment: Unfortunately, only 1 type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored), as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests). Instead of putting all types in the parameter, you can just remove the type filter as it will search regardless of type(meaning, all).